# How do I access a method from another form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm doing a projectile motion project and I want a live animation to play when you press a button. The button opens another form and to get the projectile to move I need to call a method from the first form

```
Public Class Projectile
    Public Sub UpdatePosition()
        Left = Left + 10
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is the code from the first form

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        For Each control As Control In Controls
            If TypeOf control Is Projectile Then

            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

and this where I want to call UpdatePosistion to.

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean `(New Projectile).UpdatePosition()`?  Though usually you'd make a Projectile variable ahead of time so you could re-use it without having to recreate it every time.  And also so it will retain context, which is usually what you want objects for.

Answer (score 2):

We need to cast the `control` variable in the `For Each` loop and `If` block to a `Projectile` variable. We can simplify this using the `OfType(Of T)` method:

```
For Each control As Projectile In Controls.OfType(Of Projectile)()
    control.UpdatePosition()
Next
```

The `OfType()` call handles both the cast and `If` check for us.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs `Inherits Control` or it will not be found in the `Controls` collection.

Cast the control to the type with the `UpdatePosition` method.

```
Public Class Projectile
    Inherits Control
    Public Sub UpdatePosition()
        Left = Left + 10
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    For Each control As Control In Controls
        If TypeOf control Is Projectile Then
            DirectCast(control, Projectile).UpdatePosition()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```